# How to translate to spanish Backpack?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I have a local installation with Laragon for development in a local server.
I need to know how I can translate Backpack Laravel to Spanish? 
I have read the official documentation, and I didn't find this question.

I tried to find this answer in official documentation of Backpack for Laravel, and I don't see how to make it. 
Thanks.
Table Agentes : id , nombre, telefono, email,direccion

Answer (score 2):

Backpack texts will automatically translate to Spanish after you set `locale` to `es` in your `config/app.php` - I assume you want your entire Laravel application to be in Spanish.

If you're looking for special names for columns / fields, etc, you can specify the name you want when you do `addColumn()` or `addField()`. The "label" attribute is used in these functions so that you can choose what the user sees as a label.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will make it the next time.